# php header redirect based on post variables

Tags: php, redirect

I have visitors coming to my site from 5 seperate sources, each one sends a variable in the url based on where its from, in the event these sources sends visitors I want to send them to a seperate page thats more relevant to the user

```
<?php
     $var = $_GET["var"];
     if( $var='site1'){
              header('Location: ' . "http://www.example.com/site1page");
     }else{
              header('Location: ' . 'http://www.example.com/othersites/&?var='.$var,);
     }
?>
```

however no matter what $var comes in has its going to the first header location(site1page)  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that code is the actual code you are running - it is because you are using "=", the assignment operation instead of  "==" the comparison operator. PHP lets you bite yourself this way without any sort of warning.

Comment: Thanks I feel retarded right now, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing assignment (the single equal sign).  You want an equality test (double equals sign):

```
<?php if( $var=='site1') { header('Location: ' . "http://www.mysite.com/site1page"); } else { header('Location: ' . 'http://www.mysite.com/othersites/&?var='.$var,); } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, I think that comma in the second header line is going to give you a parse error.